# ActivityNotFoundException not resolving

Tags: java, android

I want to open activity via broadcast receiver , i tried any ways , but i am getting `ActivityNotFoundException` , my activity is working on normal mode, but when i want to open it from `BroadCastRecevier` it cause `ActivityNotFoundException` error,

It is my manifest ,

```
<activity
    android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:name="com.alexis.abc.ui.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And it is my broadcast receiver ,

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent2.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent2.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
context.startActivity(intent2);
```

Here is steps :
1 - I opening application and hiding launcher icon via following code

```
PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

2 - I exiting to application and dialing a number (To triggering broadcast event) and i getting following exception

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.alexis.abc/com.alexis.abc.ui.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a permission like this:

```
<receiver
android:name="Your receiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="false" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="action"/>
       <category android:name="category" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

inside your Android Manifest file? If not, then try to open your Android Manifest file and put something like what I've posted above.

Or try .sendBroadcast() instead of .startActivity() on the last line of your code:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent2.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent2.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
context.sendBroadcast(intent2);
```

Comment: Yes i have it, my Receiver triggering and works fine, but i cannot start activity, i don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your code which you want to open the application and hide the launcher icon:

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getContext(), YourReceiver.class);
```

Don't forget to declare your `BroadcastReceiver` in manifest:

```
<receiver
   android:name="YourReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
       <!-- your intent filter goes here -->
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```